# Canvas draw advanced circle with thorns on

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know how to make circles and circle shapes with the mathematical PI, but I don't know what I am going to do if I want to make something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQpc.jpg (a circle with five thorns around on)

```
ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(0 + 50/2, 0 + 50/2, 50/1.75, 0, Math.PI*2, true)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill() // Gives me a circle, but how with thorns on?
```

I need help with drawing it, getting stuck, please help.

Comment: You should read up on sine and cosine, which you would use to position the vertices of the "thorns" you're talking about.

Comment: I got an idea, do you know how to make a star?

Comment: @user2336726 Try http://raphaeljs.com/ , it would make your work easier.

Comment: I'm not going to solve it for you. Look up sine and cosine, and learn a bit of geometry, and you'll find a solution in no time.